# CBPeripheral name in iOS6

Tags: core-bluetooth

I'm using [Apple's BLTE Tansfer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html) to simulate a heart rate monitor. 
Also I have an app that receives the simulated data.

I have question a the use of CBPeripheral:

I want to control the peripheral's name.

First I've tried to add the GAP Service and name characteristic using:

```
[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CBUUIDGenericAccessProfileString]
[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CBUUIDDeviceNameString]
```

but Xcode tells me it is not recommended. 
It also seems that the service is already included (when watching **didDiscoverServices** on the receiver side).

How can I access the name property (I want to transmit it to the receiver)?

Comment: iOS 7 is under NDA. Please do not post iOS 7 questions to Stack Overflow; use Apple’s [Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/) instead.

Comment: Hold your horses, this question has nothing to do with iOS7 :)

Comment: @eshellborn - Non Disclosure Agreement...:P for the doubt...JFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add new services just set up the advertisement in the following way:

```
NSDictionary *advData = 
     @{CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:@"<your desired name>",
       CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"]]};
[peripheralManager startAdvertising:advData];
```